# Why does this for loop compile?

Tags: java

I thought a for loop needed 3 things. Shouldn't the compiler know this will be an infinite loop?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0 ;  ;) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why should the compiler care about an infinite loop? He is not there to decide if you programmed something useless.

Comment: compiler complains if your loop is followed by some logic..                          for(int i=0 ;  ;) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
  System.out.println("testing");

Comment: @RamPrakash Yes, this is "dead code" and a compile-time error. An infinite loop isn't.

Comment: How would the compiler even know that's a useless program? Linux distros come with a program called [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29) that just prints "y" over and over forever, which is not far off from what you're doing. Granted, it's not super useful anymore; but the point is, a compiler's job isn't to decide if your program is useful, and the people who found "yes" useful enough to make it a standard app are glad of that.

Comment: infinite loop if this is the last statement in the method otherwise we get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  Unreachable code